# Error in R's "ada" package : "Currently this procedure can not directly handle > 2 class response"

Tags: r

I'm running a basic ada model, but I'm getting a weird error.

Model:

```
boost1 <- ada(response ~ . ,
              data = my_data_set, 
              subset  = as.logical(tmp_train$train),
              iter = 50      
)
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Error in ada.default(x, y, ..., na.action = na.action) : 
  Currently this procedure can not directly handle > 2 class response
```

I would assume this means that my "response" column has more than two factors, but it does not:

```
> length(levels(my_data_set$response))
[1] 2
```

Is there anything else that might cause this?

Comment: I think without a reproducible example, we have very little to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in the **subset**. The subset contained no TRUE values, thus, the subset had less than 2 classes of response. To check that your subset is correct you could try:

```
table(as.logical(tmp_train$train))
```

I believe a similar problem might have occurred if the training subset had only one response class. This makes sense - as an example, imagine you are trying to classify two different types of iris, and you only trained the model using one type. In this example, it would be impossible for the model to have any idea of what characteristics separate the two types, so it would throw an error.